# latest() helper function in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm building a small application where I'm having many to many relationship between two models something like this:

```
class Contact extends Model
{   
    public function company()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'company_contact', 'company_id', 'contact_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Now while retrieving this I want only the latest model through the pivot table or you may say relational table, for this I'm trying to implement:

```
public function getData()
{
    $allData = Contact::all();
    foreach($allData as $data)
    {
        $getCompany = $data->company()->latest()->first();
        $data->company = $getCompany;
    }
    return response()->json(['model' => $allData], 200);
}
```

But I'm unable to retrieve the latest table it is showing the same old value or the first value.
Guide me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Are you using standard Laravel timestamp `created_at` in the table?

Comment: You may need to group by company since companies can belong to many customers.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin it already there in my database even I've mentioned while defining the relationship.

Comment: @NitishKumar I'm talking about the `companies` table. When you're using `latest()` method like you do, it sorts companies by `created_at` field that is in the `companies` table.

Comment: You need to save the $data variable before it will change. 

just a small tip, don't use generic variable/function names such as $allData, getData,...... For example:

    $allData = Contact::all(); should be $contacts = Contact::all();

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin: yes you are correct I found out the solution something like this `$getCompany = $data->company()->withPivot('created_at')->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc')->first();` I'm getting the result as desired, is it the correct way? or any simpler solution is there?

Comment: @NitishKumar if you want to sort data by `created_at` that in the pivot table, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

`latest()` is a function defined in `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` Class.

```
public function latest($column = 'created_at')
{
    return $this->orderBy($column, 'desc');
}
```

So, It will just `orderBy` with the column you provide in descending order with the default column will be `created_at`

OR

```
public function getData()
{
    $allData = Contact::all();
    foreach($allData as $data)
    {
        $getCompany = $data->company()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
        $data->company = $getCompany;
    }
    return response()->json(['model' => $allData], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically idea is if you are finding the relational data from many to many relation like `$data->company()` in this question and try to sort this with latest it will sort the company table with `created_at` sorting `desc` in order to get relational latest data you need to sort through pivot tables i.e.

```
$getCompany = $data->company()->withPivot('created_at')->orderBy('pivot_cr‌​eated_at', 'desc')->first();
```

This is how I achieved the latest relational table.

**Note:** You must have pivot table in your relation, in this answer `created_at` is the pivot field I'm using.